# How do I bring in node modules in a custom TFS widget?

Tags: tfs

Disclaimer: I don't know much about javascript, node, or anything else about this world.

I'm trying to make a custom widget for my dashboard where upon loading, it will issue a GET request to an external server to grab some data and display it on the widget.

I tested some fairly simple code locally on my system and I am able to request the data I want and display it in a terminal. This does not translate well when I throw it inside a widget. I quickly learned that libraries are not brought along which are referenced in my script.

So I found http://requirejs.org which apparently would let me bring in modules to be used through the browser. But that also doesn't work so well. Edge throws an error saying

```
 SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Script error for "request"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
Content (45,742)

 HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https://my-tfs-server.com/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/publisher-name/extension/vsts-extensions-myExtensions/1.0.22/assetbyname/request.js
```

I'm unsure why it can't find the script. 
In my vss-extension.json, under the "files" section, I point to the sdk/node_modules path that I have.

Does this do a recursive search of this directory?

Also, when I create the extension, I get a bunch of warnings on text files that don't have extensions, but the build tool doesn't know what to do with.

Errors I see are all say either one of the two messages:

```
TestWidget2\sdk\node_modules\require\Changelog does not have an extension, and its content-type is not declared. Defaulting to application/octet-stream.

warning: Could not determine content type for extension .cmd. Defaulting to application/octet-stream. To override this, add a contentType property to this file entry in the manifest.
```

Do I have to explicitly mark each text file without an extension as a text file or something?

Comment: Have you tried some other browser such ad IE/ chorme instead of edge?

Comment: Ive used chrome but I had issues with it complaining about something unrelated to my problem. I’ll try it on IE and see what happens.

Comment: Last I tried with IE, I ran into a similar problem. I've since put this on hold so I haven't had a chance to look more into it.